# Annotations not being placed on map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm trying to place an annotation (pin) on the map, and the pin is not showing on the simulator (there is no pin placed). I receive no errors in the code. Below is my viewDidLoad.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var itemStore: ItemStore!
    var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView = MKMapView()

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.71304, longitude: -74.0072)
        annotation.title = "Test"
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
```

Comment: Try removing:
mapView = MKMapView()

And check if mapView is connected to controller in Storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `mapView = MKMapView()`.
This line creates a new `MKMapView` instance, while what you want to do is use the one that you created on your Storyboard. If you are not using a Storyboard, than you should use another initializer of `MKMapView` that sets its size as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a outlet from your storyboard to your view controller. Also I would probably add MKMapViewDelegate to your view controller.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

var itemStore: ItemStore!
@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.71304, longitude: -74.0072)
    annotation.title = "Test"
    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializing new **MKMapview** results in new Instance. That means nothing will be there. That's why the annotation may not get placed. Try removing that initialization and try to connect to **IBOutlet** if you have. Otherwise, initialize **MKMapview** totally programmatic with defining the `frame` for it.